# Why is it that my thumbnail PIL function won't work the 2nd time?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

> ```
> def create_thumbnail(f, width=200, height=100):
>     im = Image.open(f)
>     im.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
>     thumbnail_file = StringIO()
>     im.save(thumbnail_file, 'JPEG')
>     thumbnail_file.seek(0)
>     return thumbnail_file
> ```

It seems that my error is "IOError: cannot identify image file"...based on my traceback log.

Comment: You really need to be developing on a system where you can debug things like this. You should be able to either log your python errors to a file with the webserver you're using, or (ideally) have the web server run in the command line so it will dump you to pdb if you want to use it.

Comment: You could also try running this code by itself in the interpreter, on your local machine.

Comment: Of course you can debug it even if it's through AJAX. You just put a pdb in there as usual. Sure, that requires you to run the server in a mode where you have the server talking to the console, but that's how you should do it during development.

And if you get an error, your server must surely write to some sort of error log somewhere, right?

Comment: I agree with the previous posters.

Probably your error is something to do with whatever 'f' is, and how you obtain it. But you've not posted anything about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you are running on Windows, in which case `Image.open()` will open a file handler but does not close it.  (That behaviour does not occur on Linux/Unix - the file is closed by the end of your code, and it doesn't matter if it isn't anyway).

Comment: Found a solution.

I did .read() before...and that messed up.

you have to .seek(0) to go back to the first byte.